# iPad Pro device detection

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to detect iPad Pro device , trying to guess its height with :

```
NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
```

But it returns `1024` ! same as iPad non retina devices . any advice ?

I need to specify some codes exact for iPad Pro with this line of code :

```
#define iPadPro ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 2732)
```

...and the codes must detect iPad Pro even on iOS simulator !

Thanks

EDITED :
Some suggest use LunchScreen , but when I use it this happens (scaled down) :
[image]

Comment: You must not be using a launch screen. Supporting the iPad Pro requires a launch screen that will scale up to its larger size.

Comment: You could probably use UIScreen's -nativeBounds method to figure it out.  But, as mentioned, if bounds is the same as a regular iPad, that means that you haven't declared native support for the device (via a launch image) and therefore it will assume the app is geared towards a regular iPad size, and will simply make -bounds return a regular iPad's size then scale all of its drawing.  So, the question is if you want to know if it's an iPad Pro regardless, or if you need to be drawing at iPad Pro dimensions.  If the latter, what you have is fine.

Comment: As I said, to support the iPad Pro you have to use a Launch Screen. You can use launch images for the iPad Pro. Without the proper Launch Screen, your app is indicating that is does *not* support the iPad Pro and will run thinking it is on a smaller, non-Pro iPad.

Comment: You are not listening. In order for any app to support the iPad Pro your app MUST use a LaunchScreen. You can't use launch images for the iPad Pro. Once you add the proper LaunchScreen (which will be used for all devices running iOS 8.0 and later), then your app won't be scaled on the iPad Pro. Then you can use the code in your question as needed.

Comment: OK, now you need to make sure you main storyboard, xib, or whatever is setup properly to fill the screen, regardless of the screen size.

Comment: As I stated twice now, now that you have a LaunchScreen, the code you originally posted in your question will work. The height won't be 1024 any more. Use your original code to select the proper nib for the iPad Pro. BTW - why do you have so many nibs? The whole idea is to have one that properly adapts to the current screen size. You should need to create so many specific nibs.

Comment: Where are you logging the view's frame? What do you get for `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`?

Comment: Any ideas for checking for the new iPad Pro 9,7" ? Has the same pixels like an iPad Air 2

Comment: @rmaddy hey there, stumbled upon this question. I am experiencing the same issue and I am using a LaunchScreen but when running on iPad Pro I am getting the same framing issue as outlined in the question above..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Special thanks to @rmaddy

The proper way to detect screens sizes is :

```
NSLog(@"%f",[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
```

Now if your application runs in `Portrait` mode you can simply use this code to detect iPad Pro :

```
#define iPadPro ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 1366)
```

> Don't forget the need to use a LaunchScreen or the app won't take advantage of the iPad Pro's larger screen

Comment: Don't forget the need to use a LaunchScreen or the app won't take advantage of the iPad Pro's larger screen.

Comment: iPad Pro comes in 9.7 inch now, this fails

Comment: @jjxtra, it doesn't fail since the height point still remains at 1366 in 9.7inch.

Comment: @GeneCode not according to this: http://m.gsmarena.com/apple_ipad_pro_9_7-7984.php

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info.

Comment: the above solution doesnt work in iPad pro 12.9 simulator

Answer (score 9):

detect iPad pro 12.9 inch no matter device's orientation

```
#define iPadPro12 (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.height == 2732)
```

Comment: the above solution doesnt work in iPad pro 12.9 simulator. On doing: po [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height -> it prints 2048 and on doing po [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height -> it prints 1024

Answer (score 5):

Here is a check that would work regardless of the device orientation:

```
- (BOOL)isIpadPro
{
    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGFloat width = mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.width / mainScreen.nativeScale;
    CGFloat height = mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.height / mainScreen.nativeScale;
    BOOL isIpad = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
    BOOL hasIPadProWidth = fabs(width - 1024.f) < DBL_EPSILON;
    BOOL hasIPadProHeight = fabs(height - 1366.f) < DBL_EPSILON;
    return isIpad && hasIPadProHeight && hasIPadProWidth;
}
```

**Please note that this only works for iOS8+**

Comment: For the last two booleans, shouldn't the first be `hasIPadProWidth`, and the second `hasIPadProHeight`?

Comment: Working well for me. I put it in a Category as a class method on UIDevice.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Mc.Lover

A little update for both `Portrait` and `Landscape` orientations:

```
if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 1366 || [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width == 1366))) {
//iPad Pro
}
```

Answer (score 5):

### Fixed Solution for Swift 3+

There are two solutions , First one I've used in my project , you can use any one of them.

1- Using Macro

2- Using Extension

## Using Macro

```
#define iPadPro129 (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && 
                                  UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.height == 2732) 

#define iPadPro105 (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && 
                                  UIScreen.mainScreen.nativeBounds.size.height == 2224)
```

## Using Extension

```
extension UIDevice {

    // for ipad pro 12.9 device
     public var isPadPro129: Bool {
         if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad 
             && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height == 2732) {
              return true
         }
         return false
     }



  // for ipad pro 10.5 device
     public var isPadPro105: Bool {
         if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad 
             && UIScreen.main. nativeBounds.size.height == 2224) {
              return true
         }
         return false
     }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift version of D1mers0n's solution.

```
func isIpadPro() -> Bool
{
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad &&
        (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 1366 || UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 1366)) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Following Swift3 standards/practices, a better approach would be:

```
extension UIDevice {

     public var isiPadPro12: Bool {
         if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad 
             && (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1366 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1366) {
              return true
         }
         return false
     }

}
```

Adding this to an `extension` of `UIDevice` allows you to call, which is tidy:

`UIDevice.current.isiPadPro12`

One day Apple will finally give us an `enum` value!

Answer (score 2):

My solution in Objective-C using macros:

```
define IS_IPAD_DEVICE   ([(NSString *)[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"])    
define IS_IPAD_IDIOM    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)    
define IS_IPAD          (IS_IPAD_DEVICE || IS_IPAD_IDIOM)    
define IS_PORTRAIT                              UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])    
define IS_LANDSCAPE                             UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])    
define IS_IPAD_PRO_12_9  (IS_IPAD && ((IS_PORTRAIT && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 2732.0) || (IS_LANDSCAPE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 2048.0)))    
define IS_IPAD_PRO_11    (IS_IPAD && ((IS_PORTRAIT && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 2388.0) || (IS_LANDSCAPE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 1668.0)))    
define IS_IPAD_PRO_10_5  (IS_IPAD && ((IS_PORTRAIT && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 2224.0) || (IS_LANDSCAPE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 1668.0)))    
define IS_IPAD_OR_MINI   (IS_IPAD && ((IS_PORTRAIT && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 2048.0) || (IS_LANDSCAPE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeBounds].size.height == 1536.0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the best long term solution, but it will work for you today...

Get the hardware string for the device...

```
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);

NSString *hardwareString = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
free(machine);
```

Compare the hardware string to these hw strings:

```
if ([hardwareString isEqualToString:@"iPad6,7"] || [hardwareString isEqualToString:@"iPad6,8"]) {
    // iPad Pro
}
```

If you like, I have a class that wraps all of this that I could send you. Never really polished it enough to make a pod out of it, but I do have it available if need be.

Comment: Do not do this. There are proper ways to detect the screen size.

Comment: I believe the question is how do you detect the device type not the screen size.

Comment: But the only reason to detect the device type (at least for the OP's question) is to handle things differently based on screen size.

Comment: I'm not reading it that way. Sounds like Mc.Lover wants to do something specific on the iPad Pro using the screen size as a metric for figuring out iPad vs. Pro. Either way. My approach will work for today if you need to get your product out there, but it needs maintenance every time Apple releases a new model--the HW strings need to be updated.

Comment: The OP's code will work too once they properly update their app to support the iPad Pro. That's why there is no need to look at the hardware string.

Comment: No. Simulators have their own hardware strings.

Comment: You can mock the hwstring in he simulator.

Comment: This is another reason not to use this answer. It doesn't work in the simulator. Add proper support for the iPad Pro (Launch Screen) and the original code will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 Version of Justin Domnitz's solution of D1mers0n's solution:

```
func isIpadPro12() -> Bool
    {
        if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad 
        && (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height == 1366 || UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 1366)) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: Would be better as a variable rather than a func, check my approach which follows swift3 practices

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, for [swift3](/questions/tagged/swift3):

```
extension UIDevice {

    public class var isiPad: Bool {
        return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad
    }

    public class var isiPadPro129: Bool {
        return isiPad && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height == 2732
    }

    public class var isiPadPro97: Bool {
        return isiPad && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.size.height == 2048
    }

    public class var isiPadPro: Bool {
        return isiPad && (isiPadPro97 || isiPadPro129)
    }

}
```